# 401 Unauthorized when trying to resolve org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.2.4

Tags: java, gradle, tomcat, spring-security, saml

So, I am trying to build the sample spring security saml project provided in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html but i get the following error when I try to build:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'spring-security-saml'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.2.4.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.2.4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-tomcat-plugin/1.2.4/gradle-tomcat-plugin-1.2.4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-tomcat-plugin/1.2.4/gradle-tomcat-plugin-1.2.4.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

I cannot find a clear explanation for this but even if i try to navigate to https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-tomcat-plugin/1.2.4/gradle-tomcat-plugin-1.2.4.pom on the browser i get the same error.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had the same problem, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22170251/4782694) answer it's due to the fact that spring repos  cache artifact and when the artifact hasn't yet been cached it returns 401.
I solved this problem simply adding `jcenter` to the my configured repositories in `gralde.build` like the following  :

```
repositories {
         jcenter()
         maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
}
```